# Cannot find any files

Tags: c, linux, io, ide

I'm just starting out with C.
In my program the user enters a file name and then I check if the file exists.

Here's the code so far:

```
    printf("Enter the file name:\n");
    char filename[50];
    fgets(filename, 50, stdin);
    printf("You have entered %s\n", filename);
    if( access(filename, F_OK ) == -1 )
    {
        printf("File not found/access denied.\n");
    }
```

In the same directory as the program itself I got a file named "steps".
However whenever I enter steps or ./steps or even ~/steps I get the file not found error message.

What's the issue here?

By the way I'm on Linux (Ubuntu).
Also, I know for certain that I have access to the file - so it's not a matter of permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` includes the trailing New-Line in the buffer so `access` thinks that is part of the file name. You need to strip off the New-Line.

After the fgets, add the following line:

```
if (filename[strlen(filename)-1] == '\n') filename[strlen(filename)-1] = '\0';
```

to strip it off.

**Edit:** As @alk noted (thanks), this should be:

```
if (strlen(filename) > 0 && filename[strlen(filename)-1] == '\n')
    filename[strlen(filename)-1] = '\0';
```

`&&` will not evaluate the right side if the left side evaluates to `false` so there is no chance of going outside the array bounds.

Comment: You should test the result of `strlen(filename)` against `0` before doing as proposed, otherwise the code might run into undefined behaviour accessing the `MAXSIZET`st element of `filename`. Also this gives you the opportunity to store the result and offers the possiblities to avoid unnecessarly calling the expensive `strlen()` multiple times for the same argument.

Answer (score 1):

Because `fgets()` adds `\n` before null character.

For example if you enter "abcd" this would become "abcd\n"

After reading file name, just replace `\n` with null character

```
 fgets(filename, 50, stdin); 

 if(filename[strlen(filename)-1]=='\n')
    filename[strlen(filename)-1]='\0';
```

Comment: You should test the result of `strlen(filename)` against `0` before doing as proposed, otherwise the code might run into undefined behaviour accessing the `MAXSIZET`st element of `filename`. Also this gives you the opportunity to store the result and offers the possiblities to avoid unnecessarly calling the expensive `strlen()` multiple times for the same argument.

Comment: Worthy to check `(strlen(filename)!=0)` before doing as proposed.when `strlen(filename) becomes 0` in the above proposal.